# SWIFT Variable used before being initialized

Tags: swift

I want to know why this code will not run. The error appears on the very last line (the print statement) (the last "letter grade") and says

> "Variable 'letterGrade' used before being initialized"

```
let score = 86
var letterGrade: Character

if(score >= 90)
{
    letterGrade = "A"
}
else if(score >= 80)
{
    letterGrade = "C"
}
else if (score >= 70)
{
    letterGrade = "C"
}
else if (score >= 60)
{
    letterGrade = "D"
}
else if (score > 0)
{
    letterGrade = "F"
}
print("Your letter grade is \(letterGrade)")
```

Comment: Try this var letterGrade = "F"

Comment: What would happen if `score` is zero?

Comment: If you enter `[swift] Variable used before being initialized` into the Stack Overflow search field then you'll find many questions about the same error message, with solutions.

Comment: `var letterGrade: Character!` put ! at the end

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is used before being assigned a grade (the compiler does not know that you've covered all the cases in your if statements before throwing this error - and in fact you haven't covered zero as @MartinR tells you ).

You could have a **default value** (in the UK a "U" is ungraded) by changing line 2 to

```
var letterGrade: Character = "U"
```

and better still use **type inference** to say

```
var letterGrade = "U"
```

You might also like to use a switch for this type of problem - look in the Swift documents using this link - https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html

But here is my version of your code using **a switch**

```
let score = 86

var letterGrade: Character

switch score {

case 90 ..< 100:
    print("A")
case (80 ..< 90):
    print("B")
case (70 ..< 80):
    print("C")
case (0 ..< 70):
    print("D")
default:
    print("F")
}
```

This overcomes the problem of your compiler error.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a variable before initializing it (giving it an initial value).

You handled the cases where `score >= 90` and `score >= 80` and `score >= 70` and `score >= 60` and `score > 0`.

What if score was equal to 0? this case isn't handled, if it happened the variable `letterGrade` will stay uninitialized.

To fix this, you can use the answer by @stevenpcurtis, or you can replace the last `else if` statement with `else` only.

Also consider using a `switch` statement with a `default` case.